# How do I return Json object from my OData action method

Tags: c#, odata

I have the Odata Action method which accepts Odata query. which parses it and generates a SPARQL query. My SPARQL query when runs on the server, returns me a Json result. But my Odata action method restricts me to write return type as IEnumerable/ IQueryable. How do I able to return the Json object?

My action method is :

```
public JsonResult<dynamic> Get(ODataQueryOptions ODataQuery) 
    {
        OdataParser parser = new OdataParser();
        var properties = parser.propertyExtractionLogic(ODataQuery);
        var Query = GenerateSPARQL(properties);
        var Result = ApplyQueryOption(Query);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Show some code that you did so far?

Comment: please see the edited question

Comment: did you try this? => `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: and try to keep action method return type only `JsonResult` instead if `JsonResult<dynamic>`